# angular-generator error with lodash

Tags: angularjs, lodash, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to run angular generator

I try to run grunt but get the following error

> Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task Warning:
>   /Users/HSolutions/Desktop/Mobile400/stairs/node_modules/grunt-wiredep/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:6619
>   }); ^ Unexpected token } Use --force to continue.

When I look at the file the lodash file is just cut off.

```
lodash.findLast = findLast;
lodash.findLastIndex = findLastIndex;
lodash.findLastKey =
```

Comment: Feels like inconsistent package... try `npm cache clean`, delete `node_modules` folder and run fresh `npm install`.

Comment: Should I have to install all the modules individually? seems like that should all be taken care of.

Comment: I ended up having to do `npm cache clean`, delete node_modules, `npm install`, `bower install`, `npm install karma --save-dev`, create a new karma config file, install a bunch of karma modules then it still gave me errors but I was able to do a grunt serve

Comment: is angular generator still supported?

Comment: Yes, generator seems under [active development](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/commits/master).